# approximate distance of the route

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to calculate the approximate distance of the route. In the getPoints method I am requesting all the route points from the database and writing them into the array. This part works well and as expected. Here you can see the code snippet:

```
public ArrayList<Double> getPoints() {
    ArrayList<Double> location = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from " + Table_Name_Location, null);
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Lat"));
            Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longi"));
            location.add(latitude);
            location.add(longitude);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return location;
}

private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2))
            + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2))
            * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist);
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}
```

However, when the time comes to the calculating the distance itself the problem occurs. For some reason the Haversine formula calculates the distances incorrectly. We recon, that the problem somewhere in the distance method, but we cannot identify it ourself. We have compared our implementation of Haversine formula, but haven’t found any differences with the original one.

Comment: You forgot to tell what the distance should be and which distance you got instead.

Comment: You could rather use two predefined lat,lon values and then call that function once. Tell expected result and gotten result. If you do so we could copy/paste the beast and try out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can check and see what might have been wrong and increase your chances of getting help.